# Compile in 32 bits mode in x86_64 architecture

Tags: perl, gcc, xml-libxml

Im running on a machine with x86_64 architecture, with 32-bits compiled Perl 5.8.4. When I trying to install XML::LibXML i get following debug message:

...
...

```
# Running under perl version 5.008004 for linux

# Current time local: Fri Oct  7 08:43:24 2011
# Current time GMT:   Fri Oct  7 06:43:24 2011
# Using Test.pm version 1.25
Can't load 'blib/arch/auto/Conftest/Conftest.so' for module Conftest: blib/arch/auto/Conftest/Conftest.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 at /app/perl/.sys/i386_linux24/5.8.4/lib/5.8.4/i686-lin
ux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at test.pl line 2
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 2.
not ok 1
# Failed test 1 in test.pl at line 1
#  test.pl line 1 is: use Test; BEGIN { plan tests => 1; } END { ok($loaded) }
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
system call to 'make test 'OTHERLDFLAGS='' failed at Makefile.PL line 495.
no
libxml2, zlib, and/or the Math library (-lm) have not been found.
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from 
  http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
```

So the question is, how can I describe in the .cpan properties (or in the Makefile.PL) that I would like to compile XML::LibXML in 32-bits mode in an 64-bits architecture?

B.R CH

Comment: I guess you're using your system-installed linux.  You might want to try installing its own package of XML::LibXML.  Otherwise, 5.8.4 is very old (perl is at 5.14.X now) so you might want to upgrade Perl and start again.

Comment: The same settings used to compile Perl itself should be used to compile XML::LibXML, so the literal question is rather baffling.

Comment: I would guess that it *is* doing a just fine job of using a 32-bit compiler and the right flags — the only problem is that you don't have a 32-bit libxml2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. above all, check whether libxml2-devel and zlib-devel packages were installed on your system as follow:

   $ rpm -ql libxml2-devel

   $ rpm -ql zlib-devel
2. if any of them were not installed, install the missing packages as follow :

   $ yum install libxml2-devel

   $ yum install zlib-devel
3. re-install XML::LibXML pacak with CPAN as follow :

   $ cpan

   cpan> install XML::LibXML

I hope that this will be helpful.
Good luck!